# since update, Problem with greek and hindi in polyglossia + tex4ht

Tags: languages, tex4ht, polyglossia

I updated my texlive (for windows) and I have now a problem when I load hindi and greek languages. Everything worked fine a few days ago. I have the latest version of `alternative4ht` when i write this. I compile the following file from michal-h21 @michal.h21 and sty file of  [alternative4ht](https://github.com/michal-h21/helpers4ht).

I keep compiling `make4ht -ul hello.tex` and the results is that I have the words `Greek Hindi` at the top my `.html`. the document seems fine. My pdf compiles finely with `lualatex`.

I put my log here
http://pastebin.com/sUgz1psG

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{alternative4ht}
  \altusepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
  \altusepackage{polyglossia}
  \setmainlanguage{czech}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}



%\addbibresource{mwe.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Hello world}

\subsection{Hello, hello}



Over \textit{twenty years} ago, \textbf{introduced} the first
double auction mechanism.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please copy the log into your post rather than linking to it since it is an important part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Every language supported by `Polyglossia` has `gloss-languagename.ldf` configuration file. With `altusepackage` we don't load `polyglossia` package, but particular language config files are loaded, in order to support captions and other language dependent stuff. Becaue these config files may contain any macros defined by `polyglossia`, we must declare them in the `polyglossia-alt4ht.sty`. The most common macros are included already, but some less common don't. They have to be defined if they are used in some language config files. It seems that this is the case with some macros used in Greek and Hindi config files. I've added them right now, so the solution is to update `helpers4ht`